# Ayuda,oracle y python

Tags: python, oracle, crud, vscode

Estoy haciendo un crud oracle y python y cuando quiero eliminar un dato, por alguna razón se me cuelga la GUI que hice, pero para insertar datos si me funciona, soy nuevo en esto de oracle.

Mi código es el siguiente :

```
def deleteData(): 
    cod_id = id_text.get() 
    if(cod_id==""): 
        Messagebox.showinfo("CRUD ORACLE Y PYTHON","INSERTE EL ID A BORRAR") 
    else: 
        connection = getConnection() 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        de = "delete from camionero where cod_id = "+cod_id+"" 
        cursor.execute(de) 
        connection.commit()
         Messagebox.showinfo("CRUD ORACLE Y PYTHON", "REGISTRO ELIMINADO") 
         cursor.close()
```

[image: AL INTRODUCIR MI ID, Y LE DOY A ELIMINAR, SE CONGELA MI GUI]

Comment: Por favor, el codigo en formato texto.

Comment: ya lo deje como respuesta